# Three.js: 2D Screenshot of 3D model without background

Tags: canvas, three.js, 3d

I have created fun 3D objects that I would like to take a screenshot of without a background. Anyone know if it's possible to do that? I've searched on Google but found solutions that capture a screenshot of the entire canvas.